# Get element by ID using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want get the id of the element that is clicked and within a specified class, and want to print the ID.

Here is my JS , I am really new JS , Please help

```
      $('.wrapinner').click(function(e) {
         $('.wrapinner').css("margin-top","0");
         $('.wrapinner').css("opacity","0.4");
         $(this).css("margin-top","25px");
         $(this).css("opacity","1");
         var r= document.getElementById(this).attributes.toString();
        document.write(r);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1) Done without jQuery object (it is **faster**)

```
$(".wrapinner").click(function(){
  //Your Code
  var id = this.id;
  document.write(id);
});
```

OR

2) Done with jQuery object:

```
$(".wrapinner").click(function(){
  //Your Code
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  document.write(id);
});
```

**NOTE** after [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)'s comment.

Use `document.write()` if really needed and is not harmful to your page OR use `console.log()`. Read [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Please use `console.log()`, not `document.write()` because `document.write()` will clear the entire document.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the native javascript object directly; `this.id`.

```
$('.wrapinner').click(function(e) {
     $('.wrapinner').css("margin-top","0").css("opacity","0.4"); // chained these two
     $(this).css("margin-top","25px").css("opacity","1"); // chained these two
     var r = this.id; // this should already reference the correct element.
    document.write(r);
});
```

Comment: Eeeck. Don't use `document.write()` because that will clear the entire document. If it's just for debugging, use console.log()

Comment: @jfriend00, I used `document.write()` because the OP used it in their function and I didn't want to guess what they actually wanted to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
$('.wrapinner').click(function(e) {    
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing id to getElementById, rather you are passing the object it self. You can get id of source object of event using `this.id` not by `this`.

*Change*

```
var r= document.getElementById(this).attributes.toString();
```

*To*

```
var r= document.getElementById(this.id).attributes.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
document.write(this.id)
```

Comment: I'm not advising him to use `document.write`. He's already using it in his code. The point of my answer was to mention that `this.id` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".wrapinner").click(function(){
  var id = this.id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.wrapinner').click(function(e) {
         $('.wrapinner').css("margin-top","0");
         $('.wrapinner').css("opacity","0.4");
         $(this).css("margin-top","25px");
         $(this).css("opacity","1");
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
```

Comment: Eeeck.  Don't use `document.write()` because that will clear the entire document.  If it's just for debugging, use `console.log()`.

Comment: sorry! I just follow the owner!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this example:**

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="CustomerScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="TraderScreen" class="rows"></tr>
<tr id="DistributorScreen" class="rows"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
$('.rows').each(function () {
    var ar = this.id;
    console.log(ar);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code..

```
$('.wrapinner').click(function(e) {    
var getID = $(this).attr('id');
alert(getID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am capturing click event on class and then finding its id and class name using parent().
demo[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/e39UZ/26/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class-first ul li, .class-second ul li, .class-third ul li').on('click',function(){
        console.log("child :"+$(this).attr('id') + " Parent:"+$(this).parents().eq(1).attr('class'));
    });
})
```